# Android startActivity with animation

Tags: android, animation

I created an `activity` ( activity no. 1 ) with 2 `Views`, one `button` and one `textView` these two views are `shared` to another `activity` ( activity no. 2 )

I use the following code to start from `activity1` to `activity2` with the shared elements:

```
Pair textView = new Pair<>(view1, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view1));
Pair button = new Pair<>(view2, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view2));

ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions =
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                Activity1.this, textView, button);

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(Activity1.this, intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

When I press the `back` `button` the `views` are animated back to `Activity1`.The animation stop from work after I `Override` the back buton with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Detailed.this, Main.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.putExtra("morph", morphButton.getMorph());
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}
```

The `startActivity` method cancel the animation.

I am trying to achieve this because I want to pass back to `Activity1` some variables. Is there a way how can I maintain the animation with `startActivity` method ?

Comment: you can use 'setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);' method as per your needs after startActivity to animate the activites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're starting a new activity in your onBackPressed instead of just calling `finish();`. You can use `startActivityResult` instead and set a result in your `Activity1`.
In your `Activity1` use this instead:

```
ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(Activity1.this, intent, yourReqCode, yourRetransitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

Then in Your `onBackPressed` set the result:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("morph", morphButton.getMorph());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
}
```

Then fish your results in `onActivityResult` of `Activity1`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case yourReqCode:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // fetch the result from data here
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```